# Kendo UI Charts - hide marker of the note

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-angular-ui

I wanted to use Notes in charts to display function equation on chart. It works but there is additional marker visible and I cannot find any information how to hide it. Please check picture attached.

[image]

Can you help me with hiding this marker which I mark on the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the series.notes.icon.visible to false

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.notes.icon#series.notes.icon.visible

Comment: I wanted to hide circle and this path below but thanks to yours link I was able to find this link: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.notes.line#series.notes.line.width

Then I set width to 0 and everything works like I wanted it to work. Thanks